# Gulp, make a task use another tasks output

Tags: gulp, workflow, html-email

I'm building a workflow with Gulp for handling e-mails and I'm having some trouble.

My gulp file compiles a jade file into html, and I then want to run another task on the html file that this task outputs. I have set it up like shown in the code below.

The problem is that, even though the console says that the 'emailBuilder' task is run, it's not doing anything. But if I run 'emailBuilder' separately after 'gulp build' it does do what it should.

[image]
Image shows that emailBuilder is run last, still doesn't do what it should.

How can I make this work smoothly?

```
//-----------------------------------------------------
// ### REQUIREMENTS
//-------------------
var gulp          = require('gulp'),
    jade          = require('gulp-jade'),
    sass          = require('gulp-sass'),
    del           = require('del'),
    emailBuilder  = require('gulp-email-builder'),
    runSequence   = require('gulp-run-sequence');

//-----------------------------------------------------
// ### Clean
// `gulp clean`
//-------------------
// Clean our compiled folder before we generate new content into it
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    del([
        // here we use a globbing pattern to match everything inside the `compiled` folder, except our gitkeep file
        'compiled/**/*',
        ], { dot: true },
    cb);
});

//-----------------------------------------------------
// ### Compile SCSS
// `gulp compile-css`
//-------------------
gulp.task('compile-scss', function () {
  gulp.src('./src/scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./compiled/css'));
});

//-----------------------------------------------------
// ### Build Jade templates
// `gulp templates`
//-------------------
gulp.task('templates', function() {
  var YOUR_LOCALS = {};

  gulp.src('./src/templates/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
        pretty: true,
        locals: YOUR_LOCALS
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./compiled/templates/'));
});

//-----------------------------------------------------
// ### Inline CSS, send tests
// `gulp compile-css`
//-------------------
 gulp.task('emailBuilder', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./compiled/templates/*.html'])
      .pipe(emailBuilder())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./compiled/templates/'));
  });

//-----------------------------------------------------
// ### Build
// `gulp build` - Clean up the builds directory and do a complete build.
//-------------------
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence(
    'clean',
    'compile-scss',
    'templates',
    'emailBuilder',
  callback);
});
```

Comment: Did you try to tell the `emailBuilder` task to wait for `templates` to be completed like so `gulp.task('emailBuilder', ['templates'],  function() {` ?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work. emailBuilder should not run until all other steps are complete, and looking at the console that is also what happens (added screenshot). I still have to run it separately after the build step for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, did not see that you are already running your tasks in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `return` statement to your tasks. According to the [gulp API docs on tasks](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname--deps--fn):

> Make sure your dependency tasks are correctly using the async run hints: take in a callback or return a promise or event stream.

If you don't return a promise or the event stream (or use a callback) the following tasks won't know when the previous one is done.

I suspect that in your case the `emailBuilder` task is run too soon.